# Mutate variable in dataframe using named vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one variable, and a named vector that shows how I want the variable to be transformed:

```
dat<-data.frame(var=c(rep("A",200), rep("B", 200), rep("C",200)))

named_vector<- c("A"="X", "B"="Y", "C"="Z")
```

As the vector shows, I want "A" in the dataframe to be transformed to "X", "B" to "Y" and "C" to "Z". Is there a way to do this transformation directly using the vector, instead of assiging the desired values manually with `ifelse()`  or `case_when()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat$var <- named_vector[dat$var]
```

or even

```
dat <- transform(dat, var = named_vector[var])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    mutate(var = coalesce(named_vector[var], var))
```